# how to use solver with countif function in excel?

Tags: excel, solver, countif, stock, variance

I have total 10 stocks and I am trying to choose 5 of them which its combination makes minimum variance. I add `countif` function in solver by making equal 5 of  `=countif(10 stocks;"=0")` function. but When I solve it but it did not work.

Do you have any idea what can I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried already so we can better assist you

Comment: Set the changing variable cells to binary and use a sumproduct() with those cells and the variance to minimize the result in the objective.

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Describe "did not work" - nothing happened, unexpected result, maybe some error?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this layout:

[image]

The changing cells have to equal 5 (sum() in cell M7) and the sumproduct() in cell C3 uses the changing cells and the variance:

```
=sumproduct(C6:L6,C7:L7)
```

I avoided countif() to use the linear solver engine...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately I am not sure if I can use sumproduct function for my problem. I am trying to find best min var portfolio by changing the weights of the stocks and to calculate variance of the portfolio, I am using cov matrix. I dont know how to integrate my work to you suggestion.

Comment: You can expand my example as you wish - it was given as you did not provide any material to work with, so I showed how to achieve something similar....